# How to bust frame busting code without sandbox

Tags: web-application, iframe

Posted this on stackoverflow, but people are apparently scared of exploit code over there.  I have the following index.html page that contains an iframe.

```
<body>
    <iframe id="other" src="http://www.example.com" width="1250" height="500"></iframe>

    <iframe id="evil" src="busted_page.html" width="500" height="500">
    </iframe>

    <style type="text/css">
        #other { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;}
        #evil {position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; opacity: 0.7;}
    </style>
</body>
```

The busted_page.html contains the following script:

```
<script>if(top != self) top.location.href = location.href;</script>
```

I have a Chrome Extension that I'm trying to bypass this frame busting with using a content script run at `document_end`.  I can access the DOM of the index.html page before the frame is loaded, but I don't know how to bust the frame busting.

I've tried:

```
 top.location.href = document.location.href
```

And several variations of that, but the page just keep re-loading that way.  I've tried passing in an argument to the iframe src:

```
iframe.src += "?v=<script>if";
```

But that doesn't work either.  I've researched how to do this [here](https://www.owasp.org/images/0/0e/OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt.pdf), but haven't had any luck.  How can I actually do this?

Comment: You could use the help of Chrome's XSS auditor. So, if you point your iframe's src to; busted_page.html?x=<script>if(top != self) top.location.href = location.href;</script>
The busting script is blocked by XSS auditor and the page becomes framable.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath This allows the page to be framed, but the page doesn't actually render.  It shows an error: 'Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.".  Is there a way to do this so busted_page.html still renders, but doesn't run the javascript inside?

Comment: Okay! It's not clear what extension is blocking the request and for what reason. Sounds like iframe's sandbox attribute is what you're looking for.